# WMP continues playing after form with WMP was closed

Tags: c#, wmp

WMP embedded in form via Windows Designer. And when i closing form with WMP it's not stopping play. What's wrong? ReleaseComObjectd doesn't work too, it throwing exception (An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The object's type must be __ComObject or derived from __ComObject.).

```
// OnClose handler
private void Watch_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    currentSerie.LastTime = player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition; // update last time of current serie

    player.close(); // close player
    player.Dispose();
}

// WMP OnPLayStateChange handler
private void player_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    switch (e.newState)
    {
        case 1:    // Stopped
            trackingTimer.Stop();
            break;

        case 2:    // Paused
            trackingTimer.Stop();
            break;

        case 3:    // Playing
            trackingTimer.Start();
            break;

        case 6:    // Buffering
            trackingTimer.Stop();
            break;

        case 8:    // MediaEnded
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { seriesList.SelectedIndex++; }); // let's go play next serie
            break;

        case 10:   // Ready
            // let's play file from the last played time
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = currentSerie.LastTime; player.Ctlcontrols.play(); });
            break;

        case 11:   // Reconnecting
            trackingTimer.Stop();
            break;
    }
}

private void seriesList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* getting new video */
    player.URL = video.Url;
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on case 10.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it's catching when form closing. But why WMP trying to play video after WMP::close was called?

Comment: Because you asked it to of course.  You only disposed its window, not the underlying player.  That one doesn't disappear until it is garbage collected and finalized.  Just stop asking it to play something else.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When you say the video is still trying to play what do you mean- that 1) the process is still happening, 2) you still hear the audio, and/or 3) the form doesn't close at all?  Also see my related but not duplicate question, possibly if someone answers it could be applicable here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842966/windows-media-player-designer-view-throwing-cpu-and-lib-errors